# struct contact { int n1; float n2; char st[10] } d1;

Tags: c

I read such a snippet code of in [5.2.  The indirection](http://www.it.uc3m.es/pbasanta/asng/course_notes/pointers_indirection_en.html):

```
struct contact 
{
    int n1;
    float n2;
    char st[10];
} d1;
```

What's the meaning of using d1 here? is it a recommended practice to define such a struct?

Comment: It essentially declares the struct and then an instance of that struct, e.g. `struct contract d1;` (in whatever scope the struct is defined). There is nothing wrong with it, but generally you would omit the `d1` and then declare the instance within the scope it is needed. Also note that `typedef struct contact {...} d1;` would simply declare `d1` as a typedef (alias) for `struct contact`. You will also see that form quite often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That simply declare a `struct contact` variable named `d1`. That is not really readable and is not used generally.

Comment: d1 is a pointer or variable?

Comment: @riderdragon a pointer is a variable... however `d1` is not a pointer, `} *d1;` would be a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, structure variables can be declared in following two ways:

1) Declaring Structure variables independently.

```
struct contact 
{
    int n1;
    float n2;
    char st[10];
};
struct contact d1;
```

2) Declaring Structure variables with structure definition.

```
struct contact 
{
    int n1;
    float n2;
    char st[10];
} d1;
```

It is possible to declare variables of a structure, either along with structure definition or after the structure is defined. However second approach is not much recommended.